# Google Map Marker shadow API V2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a way to add shadow conveniently as in V3? Otherwise my solution is to add another marker to the same location with its icon the shadow of the original marker's icon.. and with click listener disabled.. That seems bad though. Any idea? Thanks in advance!:)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Bitmap` that contains both marker and its shadow and assign it using `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap` or simply create a png file that contains all you need and use `BitmapDecriptorFactory.fromResource`.

Comment: @Arch1tect how did you manage this jump animation. I mean, bounce only the marker without bouncing shadow